# Webpack Hot Module Reloader not working with React Stateless Component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader, webpack-hot-middleware

I am having a bit of trouble with webpack-dev-middleware not hot reloading using a react stateless function, but working fine if I create a class extending component.

For instance, this works perfectly.

```
// home.js

import React from 'react'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <h1>Drop it like it's hot</h1>
            </div>
        )
  }
}
```

However, this fails miserably.

```
// home.js

import React from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Error:

```
[Warning] [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed) (bundle.js, line 1742)
This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves. See http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html for more details.
[Warning] [HMR]  - ./client/components/home.js (bundle.js, line 1750)
```

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/babel-plugin-react-transform/issues/57

Comment: AFAIK, since it is just a function, it is hard to statically determine whether it is react component or just function (the issue above mentions it)

Comment: It will not work, it's mentioned on the README of the project.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

If it is still relevant and people have issues yet, there is a way, with the version 3 that is still in dev. I'll paste here my setup for package.json and the webpack.config.js files but if you want a working example [here is the repo I created for this](https://github.com/dimagimburg/react-hot-loader-stateless-function-component-example)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "favesound-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.3.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jsdom": "^9.2.1",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "soundcloud": "^3.1.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['babel']
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
    }
};
```

you can use the repo i created as a boilerplate and upgrade the react-hot-loader version when it goes production. cheers.